# PostgreSQL tsvector tsquery Bug?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

is this a bug or a feature? I've created an index on a tsvector attribute (without using a dictionary).

The query

```
SELECT title
FROM table
WHERE title_tsv @@ to_tsquery('basic') and
title_tsv @@ to_tsquery('inst:*')
```

returns "Basic Instinct". However, the query

```
SELECT title
FROM table
WHERE title_tsv @@ to_tsquery('basic') and
title_tsv @@ to_tsquery('in:*')
```

returns no records at all. I don't see why the second (more generic query) returns less results then the first query?

Bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select to_tsquery('in:*');
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
```

so presumably matching against that query always returns false?

Maybe you want to be making a single query of the form 'basic & in:*' ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! One follow up question: if I don't use a dictionary, does this not mean that PostgreSQL doesn't use a stop-word list too?

Comment: if you don't specify a configuration, it simply uses the default, which might be 'english' (i.e. English stopwords). Try specifying a configuration of 'simple' instead, or create a new configuration with English lexical analysis but an empty dictionary.